# Problem populating DataGridView with Structured Array

Tags: vb.net, data-structures, datagridview

When I run my code, populating the array with data from a csv logfile, the DataGridView populates with empty rows.

I have tried just using a 2 Dimensional Array, I get the same results.  I suspect I need to "map" the data in some fashion... maybe?

Here is what I am currently attempting:
This first section is in a Module..., the sub in the form code

```
Public Structure DataBlock

    Public Data As String()

    Public Property xData As String()
        Get
            Return Data
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String())
            Data = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Structure

Public DataBlocks(1) As DataBlock
' end of module code
' start of form code
Public Sub test(path)
    Dim i As Integer
    LogData = IO.File.ReadAllLines(path)
    ReDim DataBlocks(UBound(LogData))
    For i = 0 To UBound(LogData)
        DataBlocks(i) = New DataBlock With {.xData = Split(LogData(i), ",")}
    Next
    DataGridView1.DataSource = DataBlocks

End Sub
```

I was expecting the table to be populated I see other examples which work, but these do not use a structured array with an array in the structure.  I could just break the array down in to 8 parts (that's my column count for the file), but I'm not willing to secede just yet.

Comment: `but I'm not willing to secede just yet.`  You kind of have to.  The grid needs to know how many columns to generate.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a bit kludgy but it works. I changed the structure to a class. It seems the DataGridView can not handle an array as a column type so I changed the array to a string for display.

```vb
Public Class DataBlock
    Private Data As String()
    Public ReadOnly Property xDataOut As String
        Get
            Return String.Join(", ", Data)
        End Get
    End Property
    Public WriteOnly Property xDataIn As String()
        Set(value As String())
            Data = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Sub New(sArray As String())
        xDataIn = sArray
    End Sub
End Class

Public DataBlocks As New List(Of DataBlock)

Public Sub test(path As String)
    Dim Lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines(path)
    For Each line In Lines
        DataBlocks.Add(New DataBlock(line.Split(","c)))
    Next
    DataGridView1.DataSource = DataBlocks
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    test("LogData.txt")
End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciate you time and effort Mary.  I learned from it, for that I thank you.  I tried the code, but it just isn't what I am looking for. It runs slow with the large logfiles I am processing and as you stated, the data is in a single column.  I went back to a Structure, defining each exposed property to create the columns.  Because the logfile structures are known to me, this will have to do.  It's Saturday morning and I now secede.  VirtualMode is the only way I can populate this much data, so directly loading the file was not possible... in case this is brought up later in the thread.